# I have a jar file with batch file where I have variables I need to pass the variables in the jmeter request and I need to get the response from it

Tags: jar, jmeter, request, httpresponse, executable-jar

I have a client server java program in jar file where client will send a message and server will get it and give it as response.
How in jmeter request body can I pass the value form the jar file and the response should come in jmeter response body?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the  following options:

1. If the .jar is executable you can call it using [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) and extract the variables from the response using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)
2. Alternative option is copying the .jar to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and calling the function which  returns the "variables" using a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)